# Syntax highligting for custom fields

Tags: custom-field

Does anyone know how to allow syntax highlighting for custom fields. None of the solutions out there seems to have support for custom fields.

Thanks!

Comment: are you asking for the post/page edit screen or front end?

Answer (score 1):

[Syntax Highlighting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntax_highlighting)

[It may be Help You](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3460696/custom-text-field-with-syntax-highlighting-for-c-in-a-sharepoint-list)  i think these are useful for u.